# Set keys with empty value in redis

Tags: php, caching, redis, jwt, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel 5.5, I can't understand why in every logout I find something in redis with an empty value.
In the other hand I put nothing in cache is that a default behaviour or what.
I'm using this package for auth:

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

like in each logout there is something seted in redis cache and after some time I find myself with a lot of keys that persist in cache.
any ideas.?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing anything to the redis server? By default, the Redis server will persist the data when you log out. Can you share code you have written to connect to the Redis

Comment: thank you for the response, this my question why and what kind of data redis persist :)

Comment: Please follow the link to get the all the data types in Redis. Link is from [Official redis documentation] (https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro)